# Send email with html Java

Tags: java, character-encoding, html-email

I'm sending email with HTML code inside and everything fine except some bug with charset I think.
My Java code:

```
 public static void sendMail(String to, String from, String body, String subject) {
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();

        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(GMAIL_USERNAME, GMAIL_PASSWORD);
            }
        });
        try {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session); // email message
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from)); // setting header fields
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
            message.setSubject(subject); // subject line
            message.setContent(body, "text/html");
            message.setHeader("charset", "UTF-8");

            Transport.send(message);
        } catch (MessagingException mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

My html content:

```
    String htmlCode =
            "<h2>ZDelivery<h2>"+
            "<br/><button><a href='"+confirmString+"'>Активировать аккаунт</a></button>";
```

And email which I got:

[image]

What I've missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encoding is transferred by the email header field `Content-Type`, which is set by the mime type argument of the `setContent()` method:

```
message.setContent(body, "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

By not setting the charset in the mime type, java will set it for `text/html` to ISO-8859-1 (which is the default value defined in RFC-2854).

Your are setting the email header field `charset`. This is not a officially email header field and thats why it is ignored by the email client.